# Convert UTCString to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

I am trying UTCString to above format. I can able to convert, problem is after conversion it shows a day before.

```
    var newDate = this.getCellDate(target);
    console.log(newDate); --> Dec 05 2014 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (Malay Peninsula Standard Time)
    cstDate = newDate.toISOString();
    console.log(cstDate); -- > 2014-12-04 --- > **Expected --> 2014-12-05**
```

Comment: What is in the `getCellData()` method? I think your problem lies there.

Comment: @MisterDood That is Sencha touch calendar functionality...

Comment: I am getting the date if i tap of the date cell of calendar

Comment: The problem is the timezone: `00:00:00 GMT+0800` = `-08:00:00 GMT` = `16:00:00 GMT` on the day before (which is the 4th). I'm not sure what the solution would be though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah i got the solution. I should not toISOString. instead i need to use toLocaleDateString

```
    custdate = newDate.toLocaleDateString();
    dueDate= custdate.split("/").reverse().join("-");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Date.UTC() method

```
var now = new Date(), // my date Thu Dec 04 2014 13:02:15 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))
    year = now.getFullYear(),
    month = now.getMonth(),
    day = now.getDay(),
    hours = now.getHours(),
    minutes = now.getMinutes(),
    utcDate;

utcDate = new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hours, minutes)); // Thu Dec 04 2014 16:02:00 GMT+0300 (RTZ 2 (зима))

Ext.Msg.alert('UTC Date', Ext.Date.format(utcDate, 'Y-m-d'));
```

Look at this "Thu Dec 04 2014 16:02:00" - i got utc time(+3 hours)

---

[Fiddle example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/eg7)